# Grouping post data upon year in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i'm trying to create timeline with laravel.
I just want to grouping posts upon year like this:

```
2015
------
post1, created in 2015
post2, created in 2015
.
.
------
2014
post1, created in 2014
post1, created in 2014
.
.
```

I just want to print posts in view with this format.

I did not figure query for this build with laravel and eloquent.

Comment: Can you show us your database table and model files? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need anything special to achieve that. Just get all posts in descending order and display them adding some conditions.

For example:

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();

$year = null;

foreach ($posts as $post) {
  if ($post->created_at->format('Y') != $year) {
    $year = $post->created_at->format('Y');
    echo $year."<br />";
  }
  echo $post->content.', created in  '.$year."<br />";
}
```